# How can I get crash report of Flutter Windows Application

Tags: android, c++, flutter, dart, desktop-application

Is there any way to get a crash report of a flutter desktop application that is running on the client's system?

Answer (score 0):

try open event viewer software then see if it show any error that is related to your desktop app.

[image]

Comment: He is specifically saying "on the client's system"